# Automatically redirect user to view controller if already paid (iAP)

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Here is the deal...

For my project I have a redirection setup after a iAP that is working fine. What i'm trying to achieve now is that if the user that already has paid goes again to the payment view controller it will automatically redirect to another view controller.

The problem now is that the user has to tap the purchase button, iAP says that the user already has paid and can purchase again for free, this doesn't make sense of you ask me ;-)

Here is the code i'm using:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if (products.count != 0)
    {
        _product = products[0];
        _buyButton.enabled = YES;
        _productTitle.text = _product.localizedTitle;
        _productDescription.text = _product.localizedDescription;
    } else {
        _productTitle.text = @"Product not found";
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }
}

- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self unlockFeature];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)unlockFeature
{
    _buyButton.enabled = NO;
    [_buyButton setTitle:@"Purchased"
                forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [_homeViewController enableLevel2];

    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"])
    {
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LoginStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterController"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LoginStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterController"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I setup the redirect correctly if the user already has paid? Can I do this another way without coneecting to the Apple server if is paid?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this without querying the servers is by saving a variable or a flag somewhere. Easiest is in userDefaults.

The value is saved whenever the user makes the purchase (or if the flag does not exist and you query the servers from Apple, which would never happen anyway).

When you open your iAP viewController, you check this flag, and if it is set you redirect to the other VC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please show me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please use this tutorial, how to restore IAP and save in userDefaults :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial